# Add empty value to cell by bash

Tags: bash

I need to put empty value to cell in csv file by bash.
I add a row and the and of the file. But I used input parameters like

```
echo "Add name" 

read name

echo "Add country"

read country

echo "Age"

read age
```

I use

```
(sed -i '$ a '$name'\;'$country'\;'$age'\;;' file
```

Output is

```
Name Country Age
```

But sometimes I do not have county, so I need to put empty value.
Output will be

```
Name       24
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following syntax as you are using CSV (Comma Saperated)

```
echo "$name,$country,$age" >> file
```

The above line gives the empty cell in case if no entry is given.